# SQL Server 2012 , lost access to database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, request-timed-out

I have experienced a weird issue a few hours ago and i cannot seem to figure out what has caused this problem.

I have SQL server 2012 installed on a windows server 2012 virtual machine.
I have windows services, Windows applications and web sites accessing a database on this server.

all applications lost access to the database for +/- 10 minutes and it suddenly just came back up again.

during that ten minutes i managed to log onto the SQL server remotely and open management studio and access all the databases but the applications still could not connect.

The database did not go into single user mode, the CPU and memory was normal, i could ping the server from my desktop.

I looked at the event log and SQL logs but couldn't find anything related to why the database could not be accessed.

I am baffled I've been trying to figure this out for the last 2 hours and i not getting anywhere.

I would appreciate any assistance
Thanks

Comment: I believe this would fit the "Database Administrators" site better - here on SO it feels off-topic.

Comment: Do any of the applications or windows services log errors?  If errors are displayed in the UI, did anyone capture a screen shot?

Comment: The only error is got was operation  timed out

Answer (score 0):

run the dbcc checkdb command.  This will check the database and tables for any corruption/errors.